# version not found: socket.io-client@1.6.0

Tags: socket.io

Suddenly I am getting 404 error while installing karma, it was working fine last day. Other npm modules in the same application downloading successfully.

```
13430 verbose stack Error: version not found: socket.io-client@1.6.0
13430 verbose stack     at setData (C:\Users\***\a\git-local\MCR\feature\RO\node\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:137:12)
13430 verbose stack     at RES (C:\Users\***\a\git-local\MCR\feature\RO\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:23:14)
13430 verbose stack     at f (C:\Users\***\a\git-local\MCR\feature\RO\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
13430 verbose stack     at fixName (C:\Users\***\a\git-local\MCR\feature\RO\node\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:29:5)
13430 verbose stack     at saved (C:\Users\***\a\git-local\MCR\feature\RO\node\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\caching-client.js:173:7)
13430 verbose stack     at C:\Users\***\a\git-local\MCR\feature\RO\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:210:7
13430 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
13431 **verbose statusCode 404**
```

I am able to download it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with our local maven repo, the repository URL was changed. 
Problem resolved when I updated the new url to the `registry` property in `.npmrc` file.

I just thought to update so that it would be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.6.0 appears to be still available on npmjs.org:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

Try running `npm cache clear` and then the install

Comment: Apologies for delayed reply. This did not helped me. Found the root cause that there was an issue with our local maven repo.